# How to detect 3 way slide switch positions?

Tags: digital-logic, switches, position

With one of this 3 position 8 pin slide switches, I want to detect all three positions:

[image: slide switch]
[image]

Required function:

- Position 1: Node1 to ground
- Position 2: None
- Position 3: Node2 to ground

If I pull an digital I/O pin HIGH and connect it after SW2, HIGH means position 1 and LOW means position 2:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuXlzL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Can't connect another digital I/O pin to any of the nodes** (I have spare I/O pins but nodes voltages are higher than 5V. even if I use a voltage divider, I can't get an Ideal HIGH from them because their voltages will vary) and nodes shouldn't be connected to each other.

How can I detect all third positions?

Comment: This requires a data sheet for the switch because there is no generic contact arrangement for a switch of this type.

Comment: @Andyaka I couldn't find a datasheet for it but I have the switch at hand and the internal connections are exactly as described in the question. what other info do you need know?

Comment: But your pictures make no sense - they don't tally with each other.

Comment: @Andyaka They both have 8 pins, tested the internal connections and the actual switch and the image matches. the only difference is the space between the first four pins which is ignored in the internal connection image.

Comment: An single op-amp has 8 pins......

Comment: @Andyaka The switch connections on my desk is the same as the image that I attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the switch operates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcpOOF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Each pole of the switch consists of a common wiper contact, 'C', which can touch one of the other contacts, 1, 2 or 3, at a time. The switch is shown in position 1.*

I think you're ON-OFF-ON requirement can be satisfied as shown on the right using only one half of the switch.

---

After details of switch added:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsjhfZ.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Does this arrangement using one pole of the switch satisfy your requirments?*

*Table 1. Truth table assuming pullup resistors on GPIO.*

```
Posn   1     2
  1    Low   High
  2    High  High
  3    High  Low
```

Comment: The slide switch that I have attached the image, do not have a common pin! It's something like this: [image](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-fxdzp2uudp/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/2222/4666/sws3connections__99338.1470693868.jpg)

Comment: See the added image to the question, it shows the internal connection.

Comment: See Table 1 in the update.

Comment: @Transistor - Position 2 in your table should show High High as neither GPIO would be connected to GND.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael. It seems I can't eat lunch and update a post at the same time. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to detect the positions of a switch like this is to arrange a connection like shown here. Then one A/D converter input on the your MCU can take a reading and directly deduce the switch position from the voltage created by the voltage divider. Careful selection of the resistor values will create voltage levels that are far enough apart that noise or dither in the A/D readings will not be a problem in setting the detection range thresholds.

[image]

Here is a simulation example with one less resistor showing some reasonable resistor values.

[image]

[image]

With a 5V supply the A/D readings for the switch detection would be in the ranges of:

1. Position 1: Reading above 2.4V
2. Position 2: Reading between 1.8V and 2.4V
3. Position 3: Reading below 0.8V
4. Switch not connected: Reading between 0.8V and 1.8V.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in ignoring the spacing.

[image]

It's a Double Pole 3 Position Switch.

'C' is the common terminal. '1', '2', & '3' are the positions.

The 3 black bands are the 3 positions of the moving contact.

Comment: That's what I thought but OP is adamant that the contacts just bridge neighbouring contacts. I too had noticed the pin spacing.

Comment: @Transistor It makes sense, maybe the switch that I have is defected. I salvaged it from something that I don't remember, long time ago. I will buy a new one today and correct the question.