# How to drive this 5-pin speed controlled DC motor?

Tags: dc, dc-motor, motor-controller, diy

I am trying to build a turntable. I want to have 33/45/78 RPM, so I bought a motor that says it can do that from AliExpress.

The motor I got is called EG530SD-3F.

[image: Motor Pins]

It has 5 pins, which run into some part (the black thing with the hole in it).

[image: Underside]

I asked the supplier about the connection and they sent me this:

[image: schematic]

I understand that I have to connect it to a switch, but where do I connect the upper pin of the switch? Is it GND, is it VCC? Does anyone know?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/500838/how-to-detect-3-way-slide-switch-positions

Answer (score 1):

It should be left floating, according to the datasheet.  The switch *appears* to be a SP3T slide switch connected so that the common terminal is connected to nothing, then A, then B as you move the tab.  The voltage/current rating is not given, so to be safe I would select a switch rated for the full supply current of the motor.  Unlikely, but it could also require the switch to be connected so that it shorts between adjacent contacts (C to nothing, then C to A, then A to B).  Purchasing parts from a reputable supplier with proper datasheets will obviate these questions in the future.

Comment: There seems to be a culture here of "please buy reputable parts", and while I can't argue against it, it's not really a problem in this particular case where the answer is clearly shown on a clear diagram, even if you can't read Chinese.

Comment: Well the OP *did* have to come on here to ask about it so I would argue that the answer is not exactly "clearly shown on a clear diagram".  Hey, I get it, sometimes the part you need isn't available at Newark or Mouser or Digikey and a part from Ebay/Alibaba/Amazon/surplus store seems to fit the bill but generally they are lacking in documentation, aside from quality and reliability issues.  I would expect a comprehensive datasheet to also answer such questions as "what does that  rheostat-connected 300R pot do?", "should the switch be BBM?", and "how much current does it need to handle?".

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue as you (the lack of documentation), and since I wanted to set the motor to another specific speed, I've opened one up and documented the circuit.

Basically, this circuit revolves around an [AN6652](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1804162033_UTC-Unisonic-Tech-AN6652L-T6B-K_C75530.pdf) control circuit, which measures the load on the motor through back EMF to maintain a constant speed under load. The motor itself is a standard DC one. The targeted speed selection is made through a feedback resistor, and the motor sold for turntable have a circuit integrated that allow for the easy setting of those speed.

[image]

As you see:

- if nothing is connected, you have 340 ohm in series with a 500 ohm variable resistor. It sets the resistance for the 33RPM setting (resistance is maximum for the lowest speed)
- if you connect 1 and 3 together (that would be C and A for you), you will put in parallel another resistor set that drop the resistance value to reach the 45RPM setting
- You have the ability to put any resistor between 2 and 3 that will be in parallel with the 33RPM one, which makes you go up to 78RPM

Note the name of the variable resistor are the same as the marking on the bottom of the casing? That's because you can punch though the foam with a flathead screwdriver to access those potentiometer and finetune the speed if you want.